# Decimal to fraction won't work for negative numbers

Tags: php, decimal, fractions

I have this script that coverts decimals to fractions:

```
function toFraction($number){ 
    $numerator = 1; 
    $denominator = 0; 
    for(; $numerator < 1000; $numerator++){ 
        $temp = $numerator / $number; 
        if(ceil($temp) - $temp == 0){ 
            $denominator = $temp; 
            break; 
        } 
    } 
    return ($denominator > 0) ? $numerator . '/' . $denominator : false; 
}
```

However, after some testing, it seems like it does not work for negative decimals. Why is this? Also, what is the solution to allow it to work with negative decimals?

Comment: Please do not [resubmit the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15046135/php-decimal-to-fraction-script-issue), but edit your current one.  Also, deleting your questions so quickly may lead to an automatic question ban.  Just a heads up and a request.

Comment: Just FYI, this function will not work for decimals with greater than 4 digits, because the `$numerator` loop runs from 0 to 1000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably doesn't work because of the way your logic is set up in your for loop. What I would do is do a check to see if the number is negative at the beginning of your function. If it is, I would set a flag to remind the function that it was originally negative, and then I would flip the sign of the incoming $number. Then, right before returning, I would check to see if my flag was set, and if it was, I would simply invert the return value.

```
function toFraction($number){ 
    if ($number < 0) {
        $number *= -1;
        $isInverted = true;
    }

    $numerator = 1; 
    $denominator = 0; 
    for(; $numerator < 1000; $numerator++){ 
        $temp = $numerator / $number; 
        if(ceil($temp) - $temp == 0){ 
            $denominator = $temp; 
            break; 
        } 
    } 

    if ($isInverted)
        $numerator *= -1;

    return ($denominator > 0) ? $numerator . '/' . $denominator : false; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize `$numerator` as `-1` if the number is negative, otherwise, keep it at `1`:

```
$numerator = $number < 0 ? -1 : 1;
```

That's all you need to change, as you can see from [this example](http://3v4l.org/nq2FC), where this:

```
echo toFraction( -0.5) . "\n" . toFraction( .5);
```

Outputs:

```
-1/2
1/2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function gcd($a, $b) {
if ($a == 0 || $b == 0)
    return abs(max(abs($a), abs($b)));
$r = $a % $b;
return ($r != 0) ? gcd($b, $r) : abs($b);
}
function toFraction($number){
$up = $number;
$down = 1;
while(floor($up) != $up){
$up *= 10;
$down *= 10;
}
$gcd = gcd($up,$down);
$_up = $up / $gcd;
$_down = $down / $gcd;
return $_up . '/' . $_down;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function toFraction($number)
{ 
    $minus = ($number < 0) ? '-' : '';
    $number = ($number < 0) ? ($number * -1) : $number;
    $numerator = 1; 
    $denominator = 0; 
    for(; $numerator < 1000; $numerator++)
    { 
        $temp = $numerator / $number; 
        if(ceil($temp) - $temp == 0)
        { 
            $denominator = $temp; 
            break; 
        } 
    } 
    return ($denominator > 0) ? $minus . $numerator . '/' . $denominator : false; 
}
```